# sql query to fetch alternate columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a `connection` table in PostgreSQL where each row is a pair of users who are connected:

```
connection:
  id
  firstuserid
  seconduserid
  ...
```

For a given user id, I want to fetch the other user id for all of their connections. This is obvious if I do two queries:

```
select firstuserid from connection where seconduserid = 123
select seconduserid from connection where firstuserid = 123
```

Is there a way I can do this in one query, returning just the other user id rather than both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `UNION`

```
select firstuserid from connection where seconduserid = 123
union
select seconduserid from connection where firstuserid = 123
```

without `UNION` you may write

```
select case when firstuserid = 123 then seconduserid 
                                   else firstuserid end
from connection 
where seconduserid = 123 or firstuserid = 123
```